# Flutter ios archive app undefined symbols

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm trying to archive an app on the apple store but I get this error, everything works correctly in debug. How can I fix it?

Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_MDFTextAccessibility", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in MDCTypography.o
"_MDFInsetsFlippedHorizontally", referenced from:
-[MDCFloatingButton insetBoundsForBounds:] in MDCFloatingButton.o
"_MDFRectFlippedHorizontally", referenced from:
-[MDCAlertControllerView layoutHorizontalButtons:actionSize:] in MDCAlertControllerView+Private.o
-[MDCAlertControllerView layoutVerticalButtons:] in MDCAlertControllerView+Private.o
-[MDCItemBarFlowLayout flippedAttributesFromAttributes:] in MDCItemBar.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Showing All Messages
Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_MDFTextAccessibility
Undefined symbol: _MDFInsetsFlippedHorizontally
Undefined symbol: _MDFRectFlippedHorizontally

Thanks!

my pod installation
[image]

My pod file

[image]

Pod in my solution:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0Ua.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Build setting search Valid Architecture:

Remove **armv7** from the list

If you are using Xcode version > 12.0 Then go project or target -> **Build Settings -> Excluded Architecture**

Then Add **armv7**

**OR**

If above do not work Then set your Run to **Any iOS Device(arm64**)

Now archive your build.

Comment: Hi and thanks for reply, i've try but receive the same error

Comment: are you using any pod or library called MDC or MDF? If yes then select that framework do the same mention in answer for these lib. as well

Comment: from what I understand mdf is nothing more than flutter material design

Comment: Please check your pods or can you add pods screenshot in your code.

Comment: Not pod file. Add screenshots of pods in your Flutter iOS project.

Comment: Added screen pod

Comment: Now select pod target and select MDFTextAccessibility and do the same in answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226887/discussion-between-daljeet-and-stefano-toppi).

Comment: @Daljeet Hi I am facing the same issue but cant resolve it. I have tried numerous ways, can you guide me?

Comment: @ZXERSTON please add exact error you are getting here.

Comment: This is what I am facing Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MDFInsetsFlippedHorizontally


Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _MDFRectFlippedHorizontally

I created my own question in StackOverflow too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72446418/flutter-xcode-error-undefined-symbol-mdfinsetsflippedhorizontally-and-undefine

Answer (score 0):

Set the parameter iOS Deployment Target of MaterialComponents pods to iOS 11.0
https://github.com/jonasbark/flutter_stripe_payment/issues/217