# Flutter Xcode Error Undefined symbol: _MDFInsetsFlippedHorizontally and Undefined symbol: _MDFRectFlippedHorizontally

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, flutter, dart

I am struggling with these for days. Searching for answers online but still to no avail.

Details of the error:
[image]

List of pod files: (I assume this is related to MDFInternationalisation?)

[image]

This is my code in podfile:

```
# platform :ios, '9.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

I tried this solution https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios/issues/10203 but error still persists. I also tried installing the latest xcode version.

Please please help me. I have been stucked for days and it is extremely frustrating. I am a flutter dev so I am quite a noob in ios. Hope to get any guidance. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying out multiple solutuions, this is my solution. Simply add this `pod 'MDFInternationalization','~>2.0` to your podfile, nothing more. There are some solutions on the internet that require us to change `post_install do |installer| installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target) end end`  It is not required. just add pod md internationalisation and make sure you specify 2.0.

After that, pod install, flutter clean and flutter run.